# Does jQuery's replaceWith() also remove event handlers?

Tags: jquery

I've looked through the jQuery Documentation for the answer to this simple question:

> Does `replaceWith()` call `remove()` or `detach()` under the hood?

I've had no luck with the official documentation; it is ambiguously defined as removing the node. But tests show a memory leak.

Answer (score 17):

Looking at the source code of jQuery (2.1.1), you're asking two different questions.

1. **Does jQuery's `replaceWith()` remove event handlers?**

   Yes. [jQuery calls `cleanData()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.1/src/manipulation.js#L445-461), which is an internal method which removes *all* data on an element. Since jQuery event handlers are stored in the elements data, they will also get cleaned up.

   `cleanData()` *also* removes the event handler attached to the element which triggers the execution of all event handlers stored  in the elements data, by calling `jQuery.removeEvent()` (another internal method).
2. **Does `replaceWith()` call `remove()` or `detach()` under the hood?**

   The *only* time it calls `remove()` is if no arguments were provided to `replaceWith()`; jQuery treats it as if you were calling `remove()` instead of `replaceWith()`;

---

**TL;DR**: jQuery will clean everything up for you, so there shouldn't be a risk of memory leaks.

Answer (score 5):

FYW if you don't want that behavior take a look a this poorly discussed thread over jQuery tickets
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13400

and for those who wont ready expect code, here's an *implementation* of the `replaceWith` that uses `detach` instead of `remove`

**with remove()**

`old.replaceWith( new );`

**with detach()**

`old.before( new ).detach();`

Answer (score 0):

**1)** with **A.ReplaceWith(B);** it will remove the A element and all events attached. All events for B have to be declared

**2)** with **A.before( B ).detach();** it will remove the A element but **keep event** for later (and will apply only to A again). All events for B have to be declared

This problem can be solved by using event propagation or event bubbling as in the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".rp").click(function(){
    let variable1 = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 6;
    $(this).replaceWith("<button class='rp'>"+ variable1 + "</button>");

   });

   $(".detach").click(function(){
    let variable1 = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 6;
    $(this).replaceWith("<button class='detach'>"+ variable1 + "</button>");

   });

   $("body").on("click", ".detach2",function(){
    let variable1 = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 6;
    $(this).replaceWith("<button class='detach2'>"+ variable1 + "</button>");
   });

   $("body").on("click", ".detach3",function(){
    let variable1 = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) + 6;
    $(this).before("<button class='detach3'>"+ variable1 + "</button>"). detach();
   });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>with ReplaceWith <button class="rp">1</button></p>
<p>with before / detach <button class="detach">2</button> </p>
<p>with ReplaceWith correct event bubbling <button class="detach2">3</button> </p>
<p>with before / detach and correct event bubbling <button class="detach3">4</button> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope that might helps someone...